# Button with action "redirect to page in this application" and dynamic actions

Tags: oracle-apex

I migrated an Apex application from "BLEU-LIGNT" theme to "universal theme", and compatibility mode from 4.1 to 19.2/20.1/20.2.
I fixed the JavaScript errors and other errors but I have an error that I can't seem to fix: I have buttons in my application that have dynamic actions (to validate data) and inside there are `apex.da.cancelEvent.call(this);` (so the execution must stop) but in my application, the execution continues and the button redirects to the designated page.

I don't know how to correct the situation.

I changed the button action to 'defined by dynamic action' and added a 'true dynamic action' with the PLSQL code `APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL` BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Please don't YELL AT US, and it's not morning in much of the world. (Greetings aren't allowed in posts anyway.) :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_in_technology#Netiquette

Comment: Also, you'd probably have better luck at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has too little example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - I edited the tags since the question is very specific to oracle APEX (the "apex-code" tag is for a salesforce product with the same name)

Comment: Can you give details of the actions of one of those buttons so we're able to reproduce ? The current description is very vague. Maybe create a reproducible case on the EMP/DEPT sample dataset. We cannot see your old or new app nor your data so any info you can provide is useful.